# How to test functions interacting with 3rd party APIs with no fixed outcome

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, tdd

I have a function which interacts with a third party API hence the results are different based on different conditions:

```
export const getDataFromAPI = async (): Promise <any> => {
  try {
    let data = [];

    if ( /* data already exists and is updated on local cache*/ ) {
      data = /* get data from local cache */;
      return {
        data: data,
        pageLoading: false
      };
    } else {

      const response = /*get data from an external API*/;

      if ( /* data on API server was not up to date */ ) {
        return {
          error: 'The data is not updated for the current month. Please contact our support team',
          pageLoading: false
        };
      } else {

        /* data on API server was up to date */

        return {
          data: response.data,
          pageLoading: false
        };
      }    
    }

  } catch (ex) {
    return {
      error: 'An error occured'
    };
  }
}
```

The function does not accept any parameters and returns different outputs based on different internal conditions.

To write a test case, I need to know the possible future outcome in advance.

In this case - I don't see any way to predict the future. My life is becoming difficult when thinking to write a test for this function!!

To explain it - this is how I'm writing the test case:

```
test("getDataFromAPI function", async () => {
  const actualResult = await getDataFromAPI();
  const expectedResult = ?????;
  expect(actualResult).toEqual(expectedResult);
});
```

What should be `expectedResult`?

## OR

- Am I writing ugly code?
- Is there a refactoring possible to this function to allow writing test cases?

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about this is to separate the function logic from the actual data API. Unit tests will help you exercise all logic (including all branches) in your function.  There are 4 code paths in you function:

- data in local cache
- data not in local cache, server up to date
- data not in local cache, server not up to date
- exception handling case

Unit tests can exercise every logic branch, giving you feedback that your function works .... independent of data source.

A refactoring that would allow you to trivially execute all 4 branches would be to inject the cache and the service api. The function could accept both arguments, and if they aren't provided fallback to the current definitions:

```
export const getDataFromAPI = async (cache, service): Promise <any> => {
   cache = cache || currentCacheImpl;
   service = service || currentServiceImpl;
}
```

This allows you to configure a cache and service in your unit tests that return the exact responses required to trigger each logic branch of your function!

---

Testability and verifiability is a feature of code! Exercising each branch allows you to know for certain that your function works correctly. After it is unit testing the issue becomes verifying that your function *actually* works with the real life datasource and cache.